# Filling between two lines

Tags: filling

I'm trying to draw a seven-patch geometry, where some parts need to be filled. The domain itself is no problem, I have the corner points and just plot lines between them. Now I need that the space between two of these lines is filled. How to do this best? I tried to figure it out for hours, but I still fail.
The points are given as:

```
{px0, py0} = {1/5, 2/5}; {px1, py1} = {1/10, -2/5};{px4, py4} = {9/10, -3/10}; {px5, py5} = {6/5, 9/10};
```

More precisely, I want the space between the following lines in gray

```
g10 = ListLinePlot[{{px0, py0}, {px5, py5}}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]; g11 = ListLinePlot[{{px1, py1}, {px4, py4}}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
```

Comment: Did you try the `Filling` option?

Comment: Yes, tried several ways... But I never got it right, probably someone can explain to me, how to do it in my case. All examples I found, where for curves, with some kind of a function. I just have those lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more flexibility, I would avoid `ListLinePlot` and use `Line` and `Polygon` directly as follows:

```
points1 = {{px0, py0}, {px5, py5}};

points2 = {{px1, py1}, {px4, py4}};

g10 = Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[points1]}]; g11 = 
 Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[points2]}];

poly = Graphics[{Lighter[Orange], 
    Polygon[Join[points1, Reverse[points2]]]}];

Show[poly, g11, g10, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: poly]

If you want the sides of the polygon to be drawn as lines, you can add a directive like `EdgeForm[Black]` to the definition of `poly`. The `Reverse` in `Polygon` is needed to make the corner points encircle the polygon in a definite sense.

Answer (score 3):

With version 10:

```
pts = {{1/5, 2/5}, {1/10, -2/5}, {9/10, -3/10}, {6/5, 9/10}};

RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[pts], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {{px0, py0}, {px5, py5}};
l2 = {{px1, py1}, {px4, py4}};
ListLinePlot[{l1, l2, Prepend[l1, First@l2], Append[l2, Last@l1]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Red], None, None},
  Filling -> {3 -> {{4}, LightBlue}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that you have plot them together.

```
l1 = {{px0, py0}, {px5, py5}};
l2 = {{px1, py1}, {px4, py4}};
ListLinePlot[{l1, l2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

And here you go

[image]

> Modification

I hope you are asking for something like this

```
l1 = {{px0, py0}, {px5, py5}};
l2 = {{px1, py1}, {px4, py4}};
l3 = {{px1 + 1/2, py1 + 1/2}, {px4 + 1/2, py4 + 1/2}};(*I just make it*)

filler1[list1__, list2__, col1_, col2_, lthick_] := Graphics[{col2, Opacity[0.75], Polygon[Join[list1, Reverse[list2]]], Thickness[lthick], col1, Opacity[1], Line[list1], Line[list2]}, Axes -> True]

filler2[list1__, list2__, col1_, col2_, lthick_] := Graphics[{col2, EdgeForm[{Thickness[lthick], col1}], Opacity[0.75], Polygon[Join[list1, Reverse[list2]]]}, Axes -> True]

(*lthick is the line thickness*)

plot1 = filler1[l1, l2, Blue, Gray, 0.02]
plot2 = filler2[l1, l3, Green, Brown, 0.02]
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

So you can choose either `filler1` or `filler2` depending on what kind edge you want, make all the plots and then combine them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, but I'd need, that the whole area between the lines is filled. So from the the endpoints of the upper curve, to the endpoints of the lower one.

Comment: In the end, I have a geometry, which consists of seven patches, which are all bound by four points, just like the ones I gave as an example here. Therefore I draw lines between the cornerpoints. Each patch is supposed to be filled by different colours. Is it clear, what I mean?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: you are welcome. BTW, if you want to plot it without axes, just change the `Axes` part in the `filler`. And depending on the location of your patches, you may have to add a suitable `PlotRange` in `filler` to make all of them appear properly when you are combining them by `Show`.