# Filling between two arrays with ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to Plot two Arrays and use the function Filling to generate a soil layer:

```
bb = {{32, 100, 2005}, {3, 110, 2025}, {4, 120, 2230}, {5, 130, 
   2130}, {6, 140, 2105}, {7, 150, 2013}, {8, 160, 2225}};
cc = {{32, 100, 1000}, {3, 110, 1020}, {4, 120, 1225}, {5, 130, 
   1125}, {6, 140, 1100}, {7, 150, 1008}, {8, 160, 1220}};
ListPlot3D[{cc, bb}]
```

[image]

Comment: Related, but in 2D: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78626/filling-between-two-lines

Comment: This is an amazing use of Mathematica and the Wolfram Language!!! I have a minor in plant sciences and took a really influential soil science course in the process, can you clarify what you might want to do with this? How are you thinking you would be representing the various layers? It would be awesome to mark it up with the layer designations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Filling -> {2 -> {1, Directive[{Opacity[0.4], Red}]}}
```

[image]

Comment: David, what format is this image in? It looks so pretty on mobile!

Comment: @CATrevillian:  I think it is PDF, but you can export the figure in numerous formats.

Comment: Definitely! Thank you! It shows the opacity accurately when I select it. It makes me wonder if we can upload 3D models somehow and observe them on a touchscreen interface

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Since the two surfaces are separated by a plane  a much easier approach is to fill both surfaces to a plane (say, the `z == 1500` plane) between the two and post-process to remove the polygons whose third coordinates are constant at `z`:

```
z = 1500.;     
DeleteCases[Normal[ListPlot3D[{cc, bb}, PlotRange -> {500, 3000},
      Filling -> {1 -> {z, Opacity[.5, Green]}, 2 -> {z, Opacity[.5, Green]}}]], 
  Polygon[{{_, _, z} ..}, ___], All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

David's method fills from the top surface to the `z == 1` plane. To fill ***between*** the two surfaces  we can

1. Create a `ListPlot3D` object, `lp3D`, using `bb` with filling to a plane below the `cc` surface (say, the plane `z==0`)
2. Post-process the output of the previous step (a) to replace the coordinates `{x_, y_, 0.}` with `{x, y, w}` using `w` from the entry of `cc` whose first two coordinates match `{x,y}`; (b) remove the polygons at the top and bottom (these happen to be in the first group of polygons)
3. Use `Show` to combine the result from the previous step with `ListPlot3D` of the two data sets.

```
lp3D = ListPlot3D[bb, Filling -> 0, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5, Green], PlotStyle -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None];
assocc = Association[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ N[cc]];
lp3D = lp3D /. GraphicsComplex[a_, b___] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[a /. {x_, y_, 0.} :> {x, y, assocc[{x, y}]}, b];
lp3D = Replace[lp3D, {a___, {EdgeForm[], ___}, ___, b : {EdgeForm[], ___},  c___} :> 
   {a, b, c}, All];

Show[ListPlot3D[{cc, bb}, PlotRange -> {500, 3000}], lp3D]
```

[image]

**Note:** If you define `disp = Dispatch[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ N[cc]];` and use `{x, y} /. disp` in place of `assocc[{x,y}]`,  and `{0, Infinity}` in place of `All` above, this method also works in version 9.